Access SharePoint Site with Access Token
I am trying to access Share Point Site using Access Token instead of passing credential in CSOM Library.
I am getting following error while accessing end point.
Same code is working with Windows Form environment
ActiveX control 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.
I have tried following code with Windows Form and it is working.
Getting Title of Share Point Site using Windows Form app, but in MVC Web API it is throwing error
Code

// MVC Controller API End Point 

        [STAThread]
        [Route("api/ATTitle")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<string> ConsumeSPOWithOAuthAccessToken()
        {
            string title = "";
            string targetSiteUrl = "https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/documents";

            //string returnUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient";

            var spoTenant = targetSiteUrl.Substring(0, targetSiteUrl.IndexOf('/', 8));

            PublicClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                                                             .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
                                                             .Build();

            var _scopes = new String[] { $"{spoTenant}/AllSites.Read" };


            var authResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(_scopes).ExecuteAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(authResult.AccessToken);

            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var token = handler.ReadJwtToken(authResult.AccessToken);
    
            var authManager = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();

            using (var context = authManager.GetAzureADAccessTokenAuthenticatedContext(targetSiteUrl, authResult.AccessToken))
            {
                var web = context.Web;
                context.Load(web, w => w.Title);
                context.ExecuteQueryRetry();
                title = web.Title;
            }

            return title;

        }



Any help will be appreciated
Thanks
